# Using htaccess to make directories inaccessible by anyone but localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to make it so only loocal scripts on the machine/web server can access /avatars/ example: profile.php?username=Jordan it has to show on that script but if i go to the link directoly it shows error 403 or whatever it needs. i used:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
ErrorDocument 403 "Error: <br /><h2>You are not allowed to access this directly.</h2>
```

but it doesnt work, why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess "order" Deny, Allow, Deny](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943042/htaccess-order-deny-allow-deny)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set:

```
AllowOverride None
```

to

```
AllowOverride All
```

inside httpd.conf

tested working:
[image]