# How can we get IP based website access?

Tags: .htaccess, web, rockmongo

I have installed `rockmongo`, and i want only i can access it via web.i have put this rule in `.htaccess`

```
order allow,deny
allow from 118.67.228.162
deny form all
```

But this deny every one including myself.It was working fine earlier

Comment: .htaccess processing is sequential. Try denying all first and then allowing the IP. So, swap your lines 2 and 3.

Comment: Still, result is same

Comment: Ouch! You should also change `order allow,deny` for `order deny,allow`. Also, please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4400412/1534704) and [this answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10078317/1534704)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upfront see [Access control by host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html#host)

> The Allow, Deny, and Order directives, provided by mod_access_compat, are deprecated and will go away in a future version. You should avoid using them, and avoid outdated tutorials recommending their use.

Your directives reject everyone, because of

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
```

See [`Order`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#order) for an explanation

> **Allow,Deny**
>       First, all Allow directives are evaluated; at least one must match, or the request is rejected. **Next, all Deny directives are evaluated. If any matches, the request is rejected.** Last, any requests which do not match an Allow or a Deny directive are denied by default.

If you want to use it anyway, see the first example in [`Order`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#order)

> In the following example, all hosts in the example.org domain are allowed access; all other hosts are denied access.

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from example.org
```

For a specific IPv4 address this would be

```
Allow from 1.2.3.4
```

If the client uses IPv6, the example would look like

```
Allow from 2001:db8:85a3::8a2e:370:7334
```

---

To find out which address is appropriate, access the web site and look into Apache's `access.log` file. At the end of the file, you will find something like

> 1.2.3.4 - - [01/Jun/2016:10:10:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 492 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"

when it is IPv4, or

> 2001:db8:85a3::8a2e:370:7334 - - [01/Jun/2016:10:10:58 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 492 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"

when it is an IPv6 address.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, but i already tried this, but still no luck.funny thing is if a use `allow from all` it works.but not works for individual ip

Comment: Well, `Allow from all` in this context does exactly what it says ;-). I just tested the first example on my system and it works as advertised. It *might* not work when the client connects with IPv6 addresses. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, stupid me, i should have checked the log first. My server is behind the an aws elb and that is and it was denied because it was accessed by elb. that is why it was not working.