# how to limit Apache to accept request only from localhost for specific url?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I want to approve only to local host to send requests to

`https://localhost:443/action/start.cgi`

---

I know I can limit access to directory.

```
<Directory "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs">
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Is there an option to block all ips beside localhost for specific path?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to add this rule to .htaccess.

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: for Apache 2.4 [this answer is well worth reading](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10078317/3536236)

Comment: is there an option to make this to affect only on   "https://localhost:443/action/start.cgi"  ?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is your local host

Comment: yes, but I dont want this to affect other path on localhost like localhost:443/hello/world.cgi