# How to prevent access to multiple file types in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, file-access, mod-authz-host

I'm trying to protect a few sitemap files from public access.
The only ones that are allowed to have access are IP ranges from our lovely Google crawlers.

For example - the Apache module `mod_authz_host.c` did the job well.
Until now....

```
<FilesMatch "(sitemap\.xml|sitemap_index\.xml|page-sitemap\.xml)$">
    Require ip 1.2.3.4
    Require ip 1.2.3.0/16
</FilesMatch>
```

It hasn't worked so far.

Where has the error crept in here?

Comment: What's not working with this code?

Comment: As I can see I have no error in my code. But the Apache isn't executing the code for multiple files. Only if I set it for one file. Example <FilesMatch "(sitemap\.xml)$">

Comment: Checking about the module:  httpd -M|grep authz_host  The result is: authz_host_module (shared) .... It's active - just to be sure...

Comment: " Only if I set it for one file. Example `<FilesMatch "(sitemap\.xml)$">`" - That doesn't make any sense. Please confirm the Apache version you are using and what other directives you have in your `.htaccess` file. Do you have any other `.htaccess` files?

Answer (score 1):

**Updating my answer** (thanks for the constructive comments from @MrWhite and @Boppy - I really appreciate it):

Using Apache 2.2 and Apache 2.4 auth directives on the same server can cause problems and/or errors. Only use the code that applies to the version of Apache to avoid conflicts

- Apache 2.2 uses the authz_host_module to control access with directives like `Deny`, `Allow`, and `Order`.
- Apache 2.4 also uses the authz_host_module for access control, but *also* uses the authz_core_module that provides the new/+10 years old `require` directive.

For example, if I want to deny all access:

*Apache version 2.2*

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

*Apache version 2.4:*

```
Require all denied
```

**About the usage of `<IfModule>`**

If I don't know the version of Apache I'm using, I can use code with conditional statements that will detect the correct version of the web server and apply the correct rule accordingly.

```
# Apache 2.2

<IfModule !authz_core_module>
<FilesMatch "\.(md|exe|sh|bak|inc|log|sql)$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule>

<IfModule !authz_core_module>
<FilesMatch "(sitemap\.xml|sitemap_index\.xml|page-sitemap\.xml)$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 1.2.3.4
    Allow from 1.2.3.0/16
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule>


# Apache 2.4

<IfModule authz_core_module>
<FilesMatch "\.(md|exe|sh|bak|inc|log|sql)$">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule>

<IfModule authz_core_module>
<FilesMatch "(sitemap\.xml|sitemap_index\.xml|page-sitemap\.xml)$">
    <RequireAll>
            Require ip 1.2.3.4
            Require ip 1.2.3.0/16
    </RequireAll>
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please consider to stop using `Order Deny,Allow`. Since Apache 2.4 (yes, it's only been 10 years) there is a totally new auth mechanism. See bottom of post https://stackoverflow.com/a/10078317/1985204 for details and links. Apache's migration guide might also help: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Comment: Thank you for the important information with the links. Very interesting! I will go diving deeper into it.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer to your question? Wrapping those directives in an `<IfModule>` container will not make any difference - are you saying that is your solution?! (The `<IfModule>` container is entirely superfluous here.) The two `<FilesMatch>` containers you have posted do not overlap, however, the Apache 2.2 auth directives will otherwise _override_ the Apache 2.4 auth directives and cause a conflict. You should never mix old and new auth directives since they can cause unexpected conflicts (as [stated in the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html)).

Comment: Hello Mr.White, I missed that when writing my answer. Exactly, in my htaccess I use different code, one for Apache 2.2 and one for 2.4. Not the overlap but the overwriting is the problem. Hence my surprise in my answer above. My mistake! I didn't pay attention to the version related code - you're both right. And after reading more information, I realized. Yes, right, there is no need for `<IfModule>` wrappers if I'm only dealing with one Apache version (here - 2.4). Unnecessarily more code and with it - as you said - the unexpected conflicts increase. Later I will adjust my above posting.